# Joining 3 tables to get Details from a Survey

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count

I have taken a survey in which they have are a few fields the has to select. Ex: workplace, years of experience, and satisfaction Level.

```
tlDetail
SurveyId QuestionId ChoiceId 
1          1           1
1          2           5
1          3           7
2          1           3
2          2           6
2          3           8

tblquestion
QuestionId Question
1           Question 1
2           Question 2
3           Question 3

TblChoice
ChoiceId QuestionId ChoiceName
1          1          HR
2          1          Accountant
3          1          Teacher
4          2          >10 years
5          2          <10 years
6          2          =10 years
7          3          satisfies
8          3          not satisfied
9          3          no comment
```

I need to write a query that will tell me how many teachers are =10 years and satisfied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select 1 x
    from tlDetail d
    inner join tblChoice c 
        on  c.QuestionId  = d.QuestionId 
        and c.ChoiceId = d.ChoiceId
    group by survey_id
    having
        max(case when c.ChoiceName = 'Teacher' then 1 end) = 1
        and max(case when c.ChoiceName = '=10 years' then 1 end) = 1
) t
```

Note that this assumes that two different questions will never have the same `ChoiceName`, which is fine with your sample data but not necessarily the case in the real world. If you want something more accurate, then you need to identify for which question you expect the answer to be `'Teacher'` or `'=10 years'`, so something like:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select 1 x
    from tlDetail d
    inner join tblChoice c 
        on  c.QuestionId  = d.QuestionId 
        and c.ChoiceId = d.ChoiceId
    inner join tblQuestion q 
        on  q.QuestionId = d.QuestionId
    group by survey_id
    having
        max(case 
            when q.Question = 'Question 1' and c.ChoiceName = 'Teacher' 
            then 1 
        end) = 1
        and max(case 
            when q.Question = 'Question 2' and c.ChoiceName = '=10 years' 
            then 1 
        end) = 1
) t
```

Comment: put an alias after select, if not it will generate error: "No column name was specified for column 1 of 't'."